# Maven Modules optional in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

Hi I've parent pom.xml like below.. , say I've 4 modules currently.. 
But at certain times I might not have all the 4 modules all the time.. 
Is there any way to make these module(s) (Child projects) optional within root pom.xml.
Which means that child project will not be present in the one branch , but will be present in another branch .. I don't want to use multiple **root pom.xml's** for different branches.. Is it possible?

```
 <project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xx.xx.correspondence</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxHudsonTP</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>xxCastor</module>
    <module>cxxYYYCastor</module>
    <module>xxCommon</module>
    <module>xxxx</module>    
  </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: I didn't get it, module of project is a in inevitable part, How you are making it optional

Comment: Afaik you can only define a dependency as optional when you defining dependencies in referencing module

Comment: I've 2 different development branches . Out of which one branch is having newly added module (Child project) , and , another dev. branch is not having that modulle ( new child project is not present) . So in one branch I've to add that newly added module in root pom.xml and in another branch I don't have to add that newly added child module. My question is Can I make these module(s) part in pom.xml to any optional say if the child project directory not present then it skips and continues to apply the goals for next modules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use profiles, like they did it for example in flex-mojos plugin project:

```xml
...
<profiles>

    <profile>
      <id>minimal</id>
      <modules>
        <module>flexmojos-parent</module>
        <module>flexmojos-sandbox</module>
        <module>flexmojos-generator</module>
        <module>flexmojos-maven-plugin</module>
        <module>flexmojos-super-poms</module>        
        <module>flexmojos-testing</module>        
      </modules>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
      <modules>
        <module>flexmojos-parent</module>
        <module>flexmojos-sandbox</module>
        <module>flexmojos-generator</module>
        <module>flexmojos-maven-plugin</module>
        <module>flexmojos-super-poms</module>
        <module>flexmojos-archetypes</module>
        <module>flexmojos-testing</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>

<profiles>
```

Comment: maven.test.skip=true makes me sad

Comment: @mhaller This was not the topic - but i removed it to make you happy ;-)

Comment: @mhaller : ? what are you talking about

Comment: @srinannap: there was a maven skip test property in one of the profiles, - I removed it, because it has nothing to do with the module problem.

Comment: comment confusion makes me smile =]