# Skip maven build for unmodified modules?

Tags: java, maven, build

I am using maven multi module build like below

```
<modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>// dependant on module 1        
        <module>module3</module>// dependant on module 2
        <module>warApplication</module>// its  a war file dependant on above modules
    </modules>
```

Present build behaviour :-
If i make a change only in module 1, maven will build even module2, module3 source files and then put module1,module2,module3 jar files under warApplication/target/lib.

Is there a configuration/way when i trigger the build, maven  verifies if any file was modified under the module, if no skip that module. For war file it will put specific
lib file that got modified. This will save a lot of time.

To check if any file got modified under module or not, maven can store last build time . Before starting build it will check if any of the file got modified after last build timestamp, if yes build it otherwise skip it.

Is there any maven plugin available for this  ?

**Update :-**

My project structure is

```
TopFolder 
.mvn directory -> extensions.xml 
 build directory->build-Projects-> pom.xml 
 build directory-> parent -> pom.xml 
 modules - > module1 -> pom.xml
 modules - > module2 -> pom.xml
 modules - > module3 -> pom.xml
```

Here is i am including modules in parent pom

```
<modules>
        <module>../../modules/module1</module>
        <module>../../modules/module2</module>
</modules>
```

.  I have included scm tag `<developerConnection>scm:svn:https://comp.com/svn/trunk</developerConnection>` in both below projects

```
 build directory->build-Projects-> pom.xml 
 build directory-> parent -> pom.xml
```

Running build from `build directory->build-Projects-> pom.xml`.
But the issue is when I change any file any module and run build from `build directory-> pom.xml`, its not detecting module changes ?

Comment: I know, it`s not an answer, but try gradle.
At least it will skip rebuild for untouched modules.

Comment: You should consider that even if you haven't touched module 2, the result of the build might be different. First of all, the build of module 2 might break because you changed some class in module 1 which is called by module 2. For the same reason, tests of module 2 might pass or break depending on module 1. Additionally, there are rarer issues like using public constants of module 1 in module 2. These are compiled into module 2 so that the byte code of module 2 can change even if you only change a constant in module 1.

Comment: @JFMeier you are right.Inthat case i need to build module 2 also. But lat's say i am sure there is nothing like this got changed which can break module 2, is there a way i can skip the build for module 2

Comment: You can simply use: `mvn -pl module1, warApplication` from the root folder (manually) (before you can use this you need a mvn install). There is no need for profiles. Or you can take a look to the [incremental-module-build](https://github.com/khmarbaise/incremental-module-builder)

Comment: @khmarbaise One question each approac in your comment 1. My pom.xml has  `<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>groupId>com.myCompany</groupId> <artifactId>customer</artifactId><packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>customer</name><version>1.15</version>` then i tried mvn -pl customer , i got the error  `org.apache.maven.MavenExecutionException: Could not find the selected project the reactor: customer` .

Comment: on Approach 2 How to configure section says `If you like to use this extension you have to define the following in your .mvn/extensions.xml file` i do not see any .mvn folder. Are you talking about .m2 folder. If not can you please tell the .mvn location. For now  i tried putting the content you mention in file extensions.xml under .m2 folder but error thrown is
 `[ERROR] The builder requested using id = incremental cannot be found -> [Help 1]` Just FYI i ran` mvn install ` from pom.xml location

Comment: No you need to create this folder in the root of your project...

Comment: Say my project structure is `MyProject > module1> pom.xml` should i create the .mvn folder under `MyProject > .mvn > extensions.xml`  Then run mvn install from 
`MyProject > module1> mvn install` if yes it did not work as it did not install `com.soebes.maven.extensions.incremental-module-builder` under my repo

Comment: @khmarbaise can you please reply on mine last comment . Looks like this is the way i need to take. But somehow not able to execute it. Does it work or  still work in progress  ?

Comment: @khmarbaise i was able to run it by putting extension tag straightaway in pom.xml. Butin maven central repo there is no 0.3 version, there is 0.2 version exist. When i ran with 0.2, it does not detect the change done in module. It just displays `skipped` when run `mvn -b incremental package` 
I had 10 modules, did change in one of the module. Then run build from pom.xml which includes all moudules. But incrememtal build did not detect it

Comment: Not in extension tag in POM you have to use the extensions.xml in .mvn folder...

Comment: @khmarbaise can you please see mine latest update ?

Comment: Best is to make a full working example which can be seen on github etc. otherwise it's hard to see what the real issue is..but where have you configured scm part in your pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise SCM is defined at last after </dependencyManagement? but before <properties>. here is the SCM tag
<scm>
  <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://jira.company.com/svn/trunk</developerConnection>
 </scm>

Comment: In which module in the parent ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Can you please have a look at mine latest updates and provide your inputs ?

Comment: Please create a full working example put it on github and make entry into the issue tracker otherwise it's hard to really see where the issue is...

Comment: @khmarbaise Its a big project and i am not well versed with maven to create new multi module project.My project structure is like this , Main Project --> build(directory)-> pom.xml which includes parent module like this <modules><module>../parent-build</module></modules> Further Parent modules includes other modules like this <modules><module>../module1</module><module>./module2</modul‌​e><modules> . Now when i change in module1 or 2 and run maven incremental build, its not detecting local changes ?  Would appreciate that if you can help me here, will provide the whatever info is required ?

Comment: @khmarbaise would appreciate if you can provide your thoughts. I can join chat at your comfortable time if it helps .Looks like I am  close, may be some tweak in configuration required.

Comment: First what I see that you are using things like `<module>../parent</module>` which shows me that your directory structure does not represent the structure of your project...Please make an example project (maybe with 2-3 modules) as your setup looks like to have something we can discuss about...otherwise it's hard to see where the problem is located.

Comment: @khmarbaise  I have corrected the project structure in mine update. This is the exact structure i have. But incremental build is not detecting the changes. I was comparing it with your sample project in github. it just a difference of directory structure. You have pom directly under top level folder but in my case its under `top level project ->  build directory->build-Projects-> pom.xml `

Comment: Please make an example on github which I can access so I can help. Furthermore putting the parent into a subdirectory is against every best practice and does not represent the architecture of your project...

Answer (score 1):

Porbably the best option is using incremental module builder.  The first time after making changes in your extension file  you need to `mvn install` and so on you can use `mvn -b incremental package` which just build only the modules which are changed from the previous build.  The github address is https://github.com/khmarbaise/incremental-module-builder

Answer (score 0):

You can use profiles to build what you know has change, as timestamp isn't supported within the pom

See here for more details : [Maven Modules optional in pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448599/maven-modules-optional-in-pom-xml)

Comment: Actually this does not solve mine purpose as i want to minimize the build time. Depending on which which module got modified, i want to build only specific those.From the link you pasted, i have to  make maven profile containing modified modules everytime . It means first i need to figure out first which module was modified and then include those modules which in itself error prone and time consuming.

Comment: I know, but you won't have much of a choice, actually. Sorry for not being able to help you more