# Avoid Unit Testing in Unchanged Modules in Maven

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing

I have a multi-module maven project and inside each module, there are some unit tests.

If I change the source code in one module and do a "mvn package", the tests in other modules are also executed.

I know that mvn "package" life cycle performs all the life cycles before "package"(compile, test, etc.).

But is there a smart way, that this can be avoided?

Comment: maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338827/skip-maven-build-for-unmodified-modules

Comment: use mavens `-pl :project1,:project2` parameter to build only changed sub projects.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I am doing the build inside my Jenkins. So how do I know which module has been changed?

Comment: @Yashu - Why wouldn't you want Jenkins to run all tests on every build?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment as I do not have enough points.
In addition to @timothy-truckle, you can use the "-am " flag to recompile and test any dependency you have; eg :

```
mvn -pl moduleX -am package
```

will compile and test moduleX and the modules moduleX is dependent on

Comment: Hi @ferrema, I am doing this in my Jenkins, so how would I know which module has changed?

Comment: @Yashu, looks like there's a problem with that in jenkins : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11964

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven profiles.

1. Create a separate profile for each module.
2. Give an easy identifying name to profiles such as the artifact id of the module.
3. Configure maven-surefire-plugin in each module **inside its profile section** to skip the unit tests in that module.
4. Now, when you build module m1 and want to skip unit tests in modules m2 & m3, activate the profiles in m2 & m3 through commandline,

   mvn package -p m2,m3